# Htaccess: rewrite all requests to https and domain to subfolder without listing subfolder

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I want to achieve the following below.

1. Rewrite (`www.example.com, example.com`) to (`https://example.com/folder`) without showing `/folder` in the url i.e (`https://example.com`)
2. Also want other requests to (`www.example.com/other-folders/..., example.com/other-folders/...`) to rewrite to `https` i.e (`https://example.com/other-folders/...`)

At the moment, I have this below:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.example\.com$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/$
RewriteRule (.*)$ /folder/$1
```

> `www.example.com` - **Works perfectly**
>
> `example.com` - **Works** but returns this error *"incorrect access detected, this server may be access only through https://example.com/folder...* then redirects but shows `/folder`
>
> `www.example.com/other-folders` and `example.com/other-folders` - **Doesn't work**

Answer (score 0):

Try :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [L,R]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.example\.com$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/folder
RewriteRule (.*)$ /folder/$1
```

Comment: Hello starkeen,  It now redirects `/other-folders` to https but I had to change this line of code `RewriteContd %{REQUEST_URL} !^/folder ` to  `RewriteContd %{REQUEST_URL} ^/$ `. I now only have issues with `/folder` when these two urls are hit `example.com` and `https://example.com`

Comment: @KcayKing **%{REQUEST_URL}** is an undefined variable ,It's **%{REQUEST_URI}** **uri**